# Git not asking for username and password when cloning

Tags: git

I am using Git version 2.17.1, on ubuntu 14.04, I am trying to clone a repository that is secured by user name and password but while cloning it does not prompt me for user name and password. I have freshly installed git, I have been searching but I couldn't find any solution yet. I have tried the syntax of cloning like`git clone http://username:password@domain.com/user/repo.git`, it does not work as well.

The error it shows is:

> unable to access failed connect connection refused.

My `git config -l` command return this

```
core.askpass=true
user.name="my user name"
user.email="my email"
```

Comment: The syntax with password is "http://username:password@example.com", so separated by colon, not slash.
Try `git credential-cache exit` to exit the credential-cache, as your password is probably cached in there.

Comment: tried it but it does'nt work

Comment: What makes you think that it's an authorization problem? `Connection refused` can have other causes

Comment: I got this link from reliable source, the only thing i can figure out by this error is authorization problem.

Comment: @AbdulMuqeet Are you sure you want to clone over HTTP?

Comment: yes, It worked now. I think the issue was with the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

```
core.askpass=true
```

This setting looks like a boolean flag that is enabled, but it's really not:
This [overwrites the program that asks for the password](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreaskPass) with `true` (a built-in executable that doesn't do anything and just returns a status code indicating success). So just remove that setting:

```
git config --global --unset core.askpass
```